# Why addListenerOnButton method is used in Android?

Tags: android

It would be really helpful is someone told me why this method is used.

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

        toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        toggleButton2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
        btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
               result.append("toggleButton1 : ").append(toggleButton1.getText());
               result.append("\ntoggleButton2 : ").append(toggleButton2.getText());

             Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, result.toString(),
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }
}
```

Comment: What method do you want to know why exactly?

Comment: There is not enough code in your snippet to answer your question. Does another method in the application call the addListenerOnButton method you showed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void addListenerOnButton()
```

is a method that someone created to set an `onClickListener` for the button in their app. When the button is pressed, a Toast message is created, like this one:

[image: Toast message]

The message is comprised of the text from some toggle buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This method makes a toast with the states of the toggle buttons when the btnDisplay is pressed

Comment: Is it a User-defined method?

Comment: No, the setOnClickListener is a method that all views have, that is called when the view is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

This method is used to separate the ToggleButtons and Button logic from rest of the App. It is used in toggleButton example on https://www.javatpoint.com/android-togglebutton-example . If you want to know why did the tutor chose to separate the toggle button logic in the first place then you should go to https://www.javatpoint.com/contact-us and ask there.